# Вопрос про указатели

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

Есть в C++ указатели, это область памяти которая содержит адрес, по которому в свою очередь расположены данные. И меня интересуют следующие вопросы:

1. Когда мы выделяем память оператором new компилятор создает некую переменную и переводит указатель на нее? Не совсем понятно, как это выглядит в памяти.
2. Если у нас есть структура (объект структуры), мы создаем указатель на объект типа этой структуры, как это всё выглядит в памяти? Создается один указатель (какой у него будет размер?) или какие-то хитрые манипуляции с указателями на указатели (структура же может иметь свои поля и методы и может на них, не видимо для программиста, что-то хитрое провернуто)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) компилятор вставляет специальный код, который вызывает функцию выделения памяти (`malloc` к примеру, хотя никто не мешает выделить  вначале много памяти, а потом выдавать кусочками). Эта функция возвращает указатель. Его значение присваивается переменной. При необходимости проводит инициализацию (то есть mov).

Пример (сильно синтетический! память не освобождается! ничего не инициализируется! только для примера!)

```
int f(int x) {
 int * c = new int[10];
 return c[0];
}
```

получаем такой где то код (для gcc)

```
f(int):
    sub rsp, 8
    mov edi, 40  # это размер 10 * sizeof(int)
    call    operator new[](unsigned long) # собственно выделение памяти
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    add rsp, 8
    ret
```

то есть, программа сама себе выделяет 40 байт памяти. Да, именно сама себе. Компилятор только вставляет вызов специальных функций (которые иногда называют встроенными (`builtin`) или "магическими" (`magick`)).

Конечно,  никто не мешает компилятору самостоятельно зарезервировать память в бинарнике, а вместо выделения просто прописывать указатель на эту часть памяти. В моем синтетическом примере компилятор мог в принципе и 4 байта выделить.

2) в случае структуры компилятор рассчитывает, сколько места нужно под структуру. Обычно оно не меньше, чем выдает `sizeof(имя_структуры)`.  Эта память выделяется одним куском. Всем полям присваиваются смещения.

```
struct data
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int * d;
};

void f(int x) {
 data * c = new data;
 c->a = 1;
 c->b = 2;
 c->d = 0;
}
```

получаем код

```
f(int):
    mov edi, 16 # это размер структуры
    push    rax
    call    operator new(unsigned long) # выделяем память
    mov DWORD PTR [rax], 1 # это поле a. оно находиться по нулевому адресу
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+4], 2 # это поле b
    mov QWORD PTR [rax+8], 0 # а указатель занимает 8 байт, поэтому размер структуры 16.
    pop rdx
    ret
```

До этого момента от классического `C` ничего не отличается. Но в `С++` структуры могут иметь конструктор. В этом случае компилятор вставит его вызов.

В том случае, если структура содержит внутри себя другие структуры, то создается комбинация. И снова пример:

```
struct temp
{
  int c;
  int d;

};

struct data
{
  int a;
  int b;
  temp f;
};

void f(int x) {
 data * c = new data;
 c->a = 7;
 c->b = 2;
 c->f.d =5;
}
```

и его код

```
f(int):
    push    rax
    mov edi, 16
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    mov DWORD PTR [rax], 7
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+4], 2
    mov DWORD PTR [rax+12], 5
    pop rdx
    ret
```

Я специально выбрал различные значения, что бы можно было найти соответствия. Как видно, компилятор просто вставил структуру и на уровне кода теперь формально есть только одна "структура":

```
struct fake
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
};
```

Остался только вопрос с функциями, которые могут иметь структуры. Здесь все просто. Обычно компилятор добавляет неявный параметр к таким функциям, в котором передает указатель на структуру. Саму структуру никак модифицировать не нужно - для  них ведь нет полиморфизма - в любом случае тип структуры будет известный и можно вставить правильный вызов.

Comment: Ну спасибо! Где Вы про это прочитали? Можете дать литературу, очень интересно)

Comment: я просто много смотрю в ассемблерный код. Это просто практика. В книгах этого сейчас не любят писать подробно(я по крайней мере таких книг не встречал).

Comment: Вставлю свои пять копеек. Помимо всего прочего существует понятие выравнивания (memory alignment). Заключается оно в том, что компилятор будет стараться разместить поля структуры по смещениям, кратным разрядности системы. Например, в такой структуре

    struct {
        int a;     // 4 байта
        short b;   // 2 байта
        int c;     // 4 байта
    }

поля a, b и c будут размещены на смещениях 0, 4 и 8 байт соответственно (а не 0, 4 и 6, как можно было ожидать). Обычно ничего страшного в таком поведении нет, но оно может сильно подпортить жизнь при прямом маппинге структур в файл.

Comment: автор вопроса похоже разбирается в чистом с, поэтому такие детали ему должны быть известны (в чистом Си без этого никак).

Comment: @KoVadim 

       В книгах этого сейчас не любят писать подробно

То ли дело в прежние времена, когда компиляторы были хреновые, и знание ассемблера позволяло существенно сократить время поиска ошибки. О чём в предисловиях к книгам по языку ассемблера без стеснения упоминали. И кто сейчас стал бы смотреть PMD (post-mortem dump)...

Comment: @alexlz, а еще в дампы было хорошо селедку заворачивать.

Answer (score 2):

[[@Alerr](/users/3147/alerr)](/users/3147/alerr), Вы правы, указатель это область памяти в которую записан адрес. Размер этой памяти зависит от архитектуры компьютера и ОС.

Если немного сдвинуться в конкретику, то в C/C++ Linux размер указателя == sizeof(long). Для 32-bit x86 это 4 байта, а для 64-bit x86 - 8 байт.

Вообще говоря, в этой памяти всегда есть какие-то биты (может все нули, а может все единички...), поэтому фактически указатель **всегда** на что-то указывает, хотя текущее значение может быть некорректным (даже не принадлежащим адресному пространству процесса). Обычно про такой указатель говорят, что он не инициализирован.

Остальное (по пунктам 1, 2 Вам уже замечательно описал [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)).